# Intersect or Except methods in linq not working in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, intersect

I am using entity framework with mysql. I have to use Intersect in one of the query but it throws the error "*Specified method is not supported.*". Can anyone suggest alternatives other than taking data to memory and apply Intersect on that.

```
public List<share> GetFeed(List<long> UserRules, List<long> ListedShares, string AuthorID)
{
    List<share> listshare = DbContext
        .shares
        .Where(x => UserRules.Intersect(x.share_rules.Select(y => y.rule_id)).Any())
        .ToList();
    return listshare;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a raw MySQL query?

Comment: Not able to get raw sql query while debugging: "An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: You need to get a grip of the actual MySQL query you are attempting to run.  If you can't write it, you might assume that you don't know it.  Anyway, if you can show us a query and some data we might be able to work around the intersect using joins or a where clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Specified method is not supported.* means that EntityFramework is not able to translate it to SQL query. Actually, in most cases, it is possible to convert it to `Contains`, which is supported. You should change your method to match:

```
public List<share> GetFeed(List<long> UserRules, List<long> ListedShares, string AuthorID)
{
    List<share> listshare = DbContext
        .shares
        .Where(x => x.share_rules.Any(y => UserRules.Contains(y.rule_id)))
        .ToList();
    return listshare;
}
```